# Spark-submit failing to resolve --package dependency when behind a HTTP proxy

Tags: apache-spark, http-proxy, spark-submit

Below is my spark-submit command

```
/usr/bin/spark-submit  \
  --class "<class_name>" \
  --master yarn \
  --queue default \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-DENVIRONMENT=pt -Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxy_ip> -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=<proxy_ip> -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080" \
  --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-DENVIRONMENT=pt -Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxy_ip> -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=<proxy_ip> -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080" \
  --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0 \
  --driver-memory 3G \
  --executor-memory 4G \
  --num-executors 2 \
  --executor-cores 3 <jar_file>
```

The spark-submit command timesout on resolving the package dependency

Replacing `--packages` with `--jar` works but I would like to get to the bottom of why `--packages` is not working for me. Also for `http.proxyHost` and `https.proxyHost` I specify only the ip address without `http://` or `https://`?

### Edit

Please note the following

- The machine I am deploying from and the spark cluster is behind http proxy
- I know what the difference between --jars and --packages is. I want to get the --packages option to work in my case.
- I have tested the http proxy settings for my machine. I can reach out to the internet from my machine. I can do a `curl`. For some reason it feels like spark-submit is not picking up the http proxy setting

Answer (score 0):

The difference between **--packages** and **--jar** in a nutshell, is that --packages use maven to resolve the packages you have provided and --jars is a list of jars to be included in the classpath which means you have to make sure those jars are also available in the executor nodes while with --packages you should also ensure you have maven installed and working in every node

More detailed info can be found on spark-submit help

> **--jars** JARS Comma-separated list of jars to include on the driver and executor classpaths.
>
> **--packages**                  Comma-separated list of maven coordinates of jars to include
>                                 on the driver and executor classpaths. Will search the local
>                                 maven repo, then maven central and any additional remote
>                                 repositories given by --repositories. The format for the
>                                 coordinates should be groupId:artifactId:version.

Comment: my question was why is the `--packages` option not working for me? Also note that the machine I am deploying from and the cluster is behind a http proxy